# In Brian Gladman's AES implementation, how is aes_encrypt_key128 being mapped to aes_xi?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm able to follow the code path up to a certain point.  Briefly:

1. The program accepts an ASCII hexadecimal string and converts it to binary.  https://github.com/BrianGladman/aes/blob/master/aesxam.c#L366-L382
2. If `arg[3]` is an “E”, it defines an `aes_encrypt_ctx` struct and passes the key, the calculated `key_len` value, and the `aes_encrypt_ctx` stuct to `aes_encrypt_key`.  https://github.com/BrianGladman/aes/blob/master/aesxam.c#L409-L412
3. `aes_encrypt_key` is defined in `aeskey.c`.  Depending on `key_len`, the function `aes_encrypt_key<NNN>` is called.  They key and the struct are passed to the function.  https://github.com/BrianGladman/aes/blob/master/aeskey.c#L545-L547

But where *is* the `aes_encrypt_key128` function?

This [line](https://github.com/BrianGladman/aes/blob/master/aeskey.c#L28) appears to be my [huckleberry](https://youtu.be/R8OWNspU_yE?t=16):

```
#  define aes_xi(x) aes_ ## x
```

So hopefully I'm onto something.  It's mapping `aes_encrypt_key128` to `aes_xi(encrypt_key128)`, right?

```
AES_RETURN aes_xi(encrypt_key128)(const unsigned char *key, aes_encrypt_ctx cx[1])
{   uint32_t    ss[4];

    cx->ks[0] = ss[0] = word_in(key, 0);
    cx->ks[1] = ss[1] = word_in(key, 1);
    cx->ks[2] = ss[2] = word_in(key, 2);
    cx->ks[3] = ss[3] = word_in(key, 3);

#ifdef ENC_KS_UNROLL
    ke4(cx->ks, 0);  ke4(cx->ks, 1);
    ke4(cx->ks, 2);  ke4(cx->ks, 3);
    ke4(cx->ks, 4);  ke4(cx->ks, 5);
    ke4(cx->ks, 6);  ke4(cx->ks, 7);
    ke4(cx->ks, 8);
#else
    {   uint32_t i;
        for(i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
            ke4(cx->ks, i);
    }
#endif
    ke4(cx->ks, 9);
    cx->inf.l = 0;
    cx->inf.b[0] = 10 * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;

#ifdef USE_VIA_ACE_IF_PRESENT
    if(VIA_ACE_AVAILABLE)
        cx->inf.b[1] = 0xff;
#endif
    MARK_AS_ENCRYPTION_CTX(cx);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I see some pattern replacement happening here.  I guess at this point I was wondering if you could point me to the docs that explain this feature of `#define`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some docs which explain token concatenation. You can also take this as a suggestion about where to search systematically for reliable docs:

1. The C standard. At [this website](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards) you can download WG14 N1570, which is quite similar to the C11 standard (it's a pre-standard draft, but it's basically the same as the standard except you don't have to pay for it.) There's an HTML version of this document at http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html, which is handy for constructing links. With that in mind, I can point you at the actual standard definition of `##` in [§6.10.3.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.3) of the standard.
2. The C standard can be a bit rough going if you're not already an expert in C. It makes very few concessions for learners. A more readable document is Gnu GCC's [C Preprocessor (CPP) manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/cpp/), although it is does not always distinguish between standard features and GCC extensions. Still, it's quite readable and there's lots of useful information. The `##` operator is explained in [Chapter 3.5](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation)
3. [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/) is better known as a C++ reference site, but it also contains documentation about C. It's language is almost as telegraphic as the C++/C standards, and it is not always 100% accurate (although it is very good), but it has several advantages. For one thing, it combines documentation for different standard versions, so it is really useful for knowing when a feature entered the language (and consequently which compiler version you will need to use the feature). Also, it is well cross-linked, so it's very easy to navigate. Here's what it has to say about the [preprocessor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor); you'll find documentation about `##` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace).

Comment: I will be bookmarking each and every reference you have supplied.  Thanks for answering my question so precisely!

Answer (score 0):

I've been at this a while but it started to become clear to me that there is pattern matching going on in the pre-processing macros of the `aeskey.c` file.  The only doc I've been able to find is [this one](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms#pattern-matching).

> Pattern Matching
>
> The `##` operator is used to concatenate two tokens into one token. This
>   is provides a very powerful way to do pattern matching. Say we want to
>   write a `IIF` macro, we could write it like this:
>
> ```
> #define IIF(cond) IIF_ ## cond
> #define IIF_0(t, f) f
> #define IIF_1(t, f) t
> ```
>
> However there is one problem with this approach. A subtle side effect
>   of the `##` operator is that it inhibits expansion. Heres an example:
>
> ```
> #define A() 1
> //This correctly expands to true
> IIF(1)(true, false)
> // This will however expand to
> IIF_A()(true, false)
> // This is because A() doesn't expand to 1,
> // because its inhibited by the ## operator
> IIF(A())(true, false)
> ```
>
> The way to work around this is to use another indirection. Since this
>   is commonly done we can write a macro called `CAT` that will concatenate
>   without inhibition.
>
> ```
> #define CAT(a, ...) PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, __VA_ARGS__)
> #define PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__
> ```
>
> So now we can write the `IIF` macro (its called `IIF` right now, later we
>   will show how to define a more generalized way of defining an `IF`
>   macro):
>
> ```
> #define IIF(c) PRIMITIVE_CAT(IIF_, c)
> #define IIF_0(t, ...) __VA_ARGS__
> #define IIF_1(t, ...) t
>
> #define A() 1
> //This correctly expands to true
> IIF(1)(true, false)
> // And this will also now correctly expand to true
> IIF(A())(true, false)
> ```
>
> With pattern matching we can define other operations, such as `COMPL`
>   which takes the complement:
>
> ```
> #define COMPL(b) PRIMITIVE_CAT(COMPL_, b)
> #define COMPL_0 1
> #define COMPL_1 0
> ```
>
> or `BITAND`:
>
> ```
> #define BITAND(x) PRIMITIVE_CAT(BITAND_, x)
> #define BITAND_0(y) 0
> #define BITAND_1(y) y
> ```
>
> We can define increment and decrement operators as macros:
>
> ```
> #define INC(x) PRIMITIVE_CAT(INC_, x)
> #define INC_0 1
> #define INC_1 2
> #define INC_2 3
> #define INC_3 4
> #define INC_4 5
> #define INC_5 6
> #define INC_6 7
> #define INC_7 8
> #define INC_8 9
> #define INC_9 9
>
> #define DEC(x) PRIMITIVE_CAT(DEC_, x)
> #define DEC_0 0
> #define DEC_1 0
> #define DEC_2 1
> #define DEC_3 2
> #define DEC_4 3
> #define DEC_5 4
> #define DEC_6 5
> #define DEC_7 6
> #define DEC_8 7
> #define DEC_9 8
> ```